# Mantis - authenticate via Windows Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure, active-directory, mantis

Trying to figure out how to configure Mantis bug tracker using WAAD (Windows Azure Activy Directory). is that possible using built-in capabilities? Following Mantis instructions with no luck - received

```
APPLICATION ERROR #1401
LDAP Server Connection Failed.
```

Is that not the same as usual AD? Wondering if someone has tried this.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with Mantis directly, but judging by the error you've provided it is looking for an LDAP server.

Windows Azure Active Directory does not implement LDAP and as such cannot be a direct replacement for AD for products that uses LDAP to query the directory.

Looking at the [features](http://www.mantisbt.org/wiki/doku.php/mantisbt:features) in the Mantis web site I can a listing of the authentication capabilies as

> ◾ Default Mantis Authentication (recommended)
>
> ◾ LDAP Integration
>
> ◾ HTTP Basic Authentication Support
>
> ◾ Active Directory Integration (patches available)

None of these map, by the looks of it, map directly to Windows Azure Active Directory.
Depending on your motivation and set-up you could look at deploying an Active Directory on a Windows Azure Virtual Machine.

Comment: Got iit. Anyway its pretty confusing from MS side to call there new solution as Active Directory where in fact it is not. WAAD seems to be similar to oAuth implementation based on on the tutorials II have reviewed so far..